# helper is not loading in Codeigniter model

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php

class  MyModel extends CI_Model {
    public function loadData()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('data_helper');
        print_r($CI->data_helper); //this is printing nothing
        $CI->data_helper->loaditems(); // method is not calling
    }
}

function loaditems()
{
    echo "hello from load of helper";
}

?>
```

helper filename is **data_helper.php**

give me you thought about this why it not working and in which case it will work

Comment: You need to add in `autoload.php` and then it will be available in whole application.

Comment: have you tried adding it to the constructor in you controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file `data_helper.php` in the `/application/helpers` directory.

In `/application/config/autoload.php` load the helper using just the word 'data'. (line 92).

`$autoload['helper'] = array('data');`

Or you can load it before you need it with `$this->load->helper('data');`

Then you can use `loaditems()` from anywhere like a normal function.

You don't need the `$CI` magic at all.

Comment: didn't see that you already answered his question - if you put my example code in your answer i'll delete mine... sry dude

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

> `$this->load->helper('name');`
>
> Where name is the file name of the helper, **without** the .php file extension or the “helper” part.

which means the following code should work

```
class  MyModel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function loadData()
    {
        $this->load->helper('data');
        loaditems();
    }
}
```

you can read more about it [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try data_helper() to call helper function.

```
data_helper();
```